# Can two different charge distributions produce same electric field all over the space?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

If I have a complicated charge  distribution and it is producing an electric field, is it possible to get the same electric field all over the space by arranging the charges differently?
Does nature allow that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it cannot be done. Charge distribution $\rho(x)$ is fixed by the Maxwell equation $\mathrm{div} \vec{E}=\rho$ for a given electric field $\vec{E}(x)$.